# Which encoding to use for many international languages

Tags: javascript, html, xml, encoding

I am setting up a little website and would like to make it international. All the content will be stored in an external xml in different languages and parsed into the html via javascript.

Now the problem is, there are also german umlauts, russian, chinese and japanese symbols and also right-to-left languages like arabic and farsi.

What would be the best way/solution? Is there an "international encoding" which can display all languages properly? Or is there any other solution you would suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think XML is the wrong approach - the PHP gettext extension (.mo/.po) is the way to go in my opinion. It is made for multilingual websites, translation catalogue etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I also thought about PHP first... [though I'm not so familiar with the gettext extension (.mo/.po)] ....as far as I remember right, when using PHP and changing the language the site gets loaded again with the new language text, right?!? But for my project I'd like to have the translation immediately without reloading. So when you click on a flag to change language the current site's text and navigation bar shall change instantly. Is there a way to achieve this with PHP?

Comment: I don't know if the *gettext* extension in PHP can be loaded via ajax. But I think it would be worth a search and give it a try. I hope you are familiar with AJAX, it is asynchronous Javascript - > Click > fires a js/ajax function which triggers a php file to load, and spit back your information.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going search for more information about this. Yes, it is definetely worth giving it a try :-)

Answer (score 4):

All of the Unicode transformations (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) can encode all Unicode characters. You pick which you want to use based on the size: If most of your text is in western scripts, probably UTF-8, as it will use only one byte for most of the characters, but 2, 3, or 4 if needed. If you're encoding far east scripts, you'll probably want one of the other transformations.

The fundamental thing here is that it's all Unicode; the transformations are just different ways of representing the same characters.

The co-founder of Stack Overflow had a good article on this topic: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

---

Regardless of what encoding you use for your document, note that if you're doing processing of these strings in JavaScript, [JavaScript strings are UTF-16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) (except that invalid values are tolerated). (Even if the document is in UTF-8 or UTF-32.) This means that, for instance, each of those emojis people are so excited about these days look like two "characters" to JavaScript, because they take two words of UTF-16 to represent. Like , for instance:

```js
console.log("".length); // 2
```

So you'll need to be careful not to split up the two halves of characters that are encoded in two words of UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, T.J.! Alright, so if I'm getting it right with UTF-8 I can also have asian, cyrllic and arabic text... but it is most recommended for western (latin) text. Correct? Well I won't use any emojis on the site.... but IF i would.... wouldn't it be safer to use UTF-16, so it the same string length like in JS?

Comment: @RostamN.: Yes, UTF-8 can encode **all** Unicode characters (just like all the other transformations can). No, it's not safer to use UTF-16 instead; the nature of JavaScript's strings is completely irrelevant to your HTML or XML.

Answer (score 1):

The normal (and recommended) solution for multi-lingual sites is to use UTF-8.  That can can deal with any characters that have been assigned Unicode codepoints with a couple of caveats:

1. Unicode is a versioned standard, and a different Javascript implementations may support different Unicode versions.
2. If your text includes characters outside of the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), then you need to do your text processing (in Javascript) in a way that is Unicode aware.  For instance, if you use the Javascript `String` class you need to take proper account of surrogate pairs when doing text manipulation.

(A Javascript `String` is actually encoded as UTF-16.  It has methods that allow you to manipulate it as Unicode codepoints, methods / attribute such as `substring` and `length` use codeunit rather than codepoint indexing.  If you are not careful, you can end up splitting a string between the low and high parts of a surrogate pair.  The result will be something that cannot be displayed properly.  This only affects codepoints in higher planes ... but that includes the new emoji codepoints.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Stephen! Sooo... if I understand right you'd also recommend using UTF-8 for multi-lingual sites. I didn't new the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane before, but I'm going to read more about it now. What exactly do you mead with "do your text processing (in Java) in a way that is Unicode aware"? Do you know an example for this, so I can see? I won't use any emojis or stuff like that.... just plain simple text and numbers in all the different languages..... though many languages like russian and mandarin look like alien symbols :-) :D

Comment: The "(in Java)" is a typo.  Should be Javascript